# Cannot Install php5-ldap on Ubuntu Linux 14.05

Tags: php, ldap, ubuntu-14.04

I just tried to install php5-ldap thru following command on terminal :

> sudo apt-get install php5-ldap

then after that I got this following error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function ldap_connect() in
>   /home/yusuf/Documents/Belajar/ldap.php on line 2

Anybody has solution for this ?

Comment: Have you enabled the modules in you Php.INI file?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found how to solve it in easy way.

- install aptitude using #sudo apt-get install aptitude
- ## aptitude install php5-ldap
- aptitude will give you solution, just chose the right one, if fail try another solution that given by aptitude